# Getting the result value of a visio shape cell

Tags: vb.net, visio

I can't seem to be able to get the right value for the cell result of a shape's cell calling Shape.Cells("Controls.Point.X").ResultIU for example. The particular cell formula contains internal variables. I want the evaluated final value of that cell.

Comment: ResultIU will give you the result of the formula in internal units, i.e. inches. If you are getting back a formula you using a different property. Can you give an example of what are you getting back from ResultUI and what are you expecting to get back?

Comment: For example I have a Controls row "Point" in shape A with the X formula as: PNTX(User.PointBegin)

And when I call A.Cells("Controls.Point.X").ResultIU I expect the X resultant value.

Comment: What is the value in User.PointBegin and what is the result of A.Cells("Controls.Point.X").ResultIU?